# Inconsistent results of integration that include the Floor[] function

Tags: integral-equations

I had thought that with the following two integrals, I was simply expressing the same idea in two different but equivalent ways, with the range of the values (excluding `x`) within the `Floor[]` term being, in both instances, in the interval `[100,101)`. Nonetheless, they produce inconsistent results. In the first integral, the sum `100+T` is in the interval `[100,101)` because of the assumptions about `T` :

```
Integrate[
 (Floor[100 + T + x])*PDF[NormalDistribution[0, sigma], x], {x, 2, 3},
 Assumptions -> {T \[Element] Reals, sigma \[Element] Reals, 
   sigma > 0, 0 <= T < 1}]
```

whereas in this second integral, `T` itself is in the interval `[100,101)`

```
Integrate[
 (Floor[T + x])*PDF[NormalDistribution[0, sigma], x], {x, 2, 3},
 Assumptions -> {T \[Element] Reals, sigma \[Element] Reals, 
   sigma > 0, 100 <= T < 101}]
```

Have I done something wrong or misunderstood something, or am I just being blind to an elementary mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MMA version 13.2

The first integral yields:

[image]

and the second one:

[image]

As you can see in the first integral T appears in: -3+T for 0<T<1 and in the second one:-103+T for 100<T<101. It is obvious that these are equivalent.

Comment: You've been kind enough to point out, ***without actually saying so***, that (and I can only I plead tiredness!), I have been completely blind. I think if it had been me who was answering, I would have had a hard time NOT saying that. ....Thank you!

Comment: Don't worry, happens to all of us  -;)